# JSON serialize gives null in the java POJO

Tags: java, json, jsonserializer

I have a java POJO with values set. i set values like the following :

```
CreateRequisitionRO[] request = new CreateRequisitionRO[1];
        request[0].setPortfolio("HEXGENFUND");
        request[0].setTransSrlNo(new BigDecimal(1));
        request[0].setTransCode("BUY");
        request[0].setInvestReason("009");
        request[0].setInflowOutflow(InflowOutflow.I);
        request[0].setTradeDate(new LocalDate());
        request[0].setTradeDate(new LocalDate());
```

and this is my json serialize method :

```
public String serialiseRequisionRO(CreateRequisitionRO[] requestObj) {
        //CreateRequisitionRO requestObj = new CreateRequisitionRO();
        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
        System.out.println("JSON : "+serializer.serialize(requestObj));
        return serializer.serialize(requestObj);
    }
```

but when i excute the program i get Null Pointer exception at this line `request[0].setPortfolio("HEXGENFUND");`

how to resolve it. and what could be the solution.

Please help me to resolve this.

Best Regards
Anto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize array element/s.

```
 request[0] = new CreateRequisitionRO();
```

Comment: thanks for the post. hope this code also would create some problem. since i sent the array of objects : `public String serialiseRequisionRO(CreateRequisitionRO[] requestObj) {
        //CreateRequisitionRO requestObj = new CreateRequisitionRO();
        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
        System.out.println("JSON : "+serializer.serialize(requestObj));
        return serializer.serialize(requestObj);
    }` how to fix this

Comment: also i now get this exception `java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input`

Comment: The calling method of serialiseRequisionRO should initialise the array